# Perforce File Status Icons Not Working in P4V

Tags: version-control, icons, perforce, status

The Perforce P4V client offers a number of icons to indicate the status of a file in the workspace versus the corresponding file in the depot. A reference guide for these status icons is documented at [About P4V Icons](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/About_file_icons.html).

However, I am only seeing two status icons in P4V:

- Green Icon -- File synced to head revision
- White Icon -- File in workspace but not in depot

Is there a setting in P4V that will enable the full range of status icons as documented? At a minimum, I'd like to be able to see that a file in my workspace differs from the corresponding file in the depot.

By the way, the version of my P4V client is:

> 2013 March 20
>
> Rev. Perforce Visual Client/NTX64/2013.1/611291

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was unable to find the answer in the “Getting Started with P4V” help document, here on SO, or by searching the Internet at large.

However, by browsing through the P4V preferences, I found the setting that enables the full range of icons. In P4V,

1. Select “Edit / Preferences… / Files and History”
2. Check the box for **“Use a distinct file icon for modified files”**.

I found it surprising that this box is not checked by default upon installation of the P4V client. Perhaps someone can offer a reason for circumstances under which disabling this option would be beneficial.

Comment: It is disabled by default as it requires additional connections to p4 server to compare the file checksums to determine if the file has been modified. It is only a problem if you are on a slow connection or have a large number of files in a changelist. I always enable this option and recommend to everyone else in the studio.